# Holomorphic function such that $Ref + Imf \geq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find all holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $Ref + Imf \geq 1$. I tried to use Liouville theorem, but it was no effective. Do you have any hints?

Comment: Try looking at $e^{-f+if}$ and see what can you say about its maximum modulus

Comment: Thanks! Your hint is very helpful.

Comment: Can we use the Liouville theorem for open ball instead of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: not sure what you mean ($f(z)=z$ satisfies the hypothesis in the ball of center $5$ and radius $1$ so one needs the fact that the function is analytic on the full plane)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\frac1f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is entire and bounded, and therefore constant.